# Google maps panTo

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm a web designer and working on my new portfolio site, come across a problem.

Using gowallas api to pull in my latest checked in spots. I have got them put onto a google map, but for some reason when you click on the links below i want the map to do a panTo, can someone help?

The page is here:
http://test.phawk.co.uk/mail/

Need any more info don't hesitate to ask.

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest v3 API:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
map.panTo(myLatlng);
```

**EDIT:**
actually change this in your code:

```
$('li.marker a').click(function () {
    var nLtLg = $(this).attr('rel');
    arrLatLng = nLtLg.split(',');

    var newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrLatLng[0], arrLatLng[1]);
    map.panTo(newlatlng);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: $('li.marker a').click(function(){
  var nLtLg = $(this).attr('rel');
  var newlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(nLtLg);
  map.panTo(newlatlng);
  return false;
 });

Comment: That is the code i am using currently.. it makes the map just turn brown.

I think it is because the info i am putting into maps.LatLng is a string??

Comment: I would explain my edit, but i'm pretty sure you can see what is going on. If not, let me know.

Comment: Works great... Is there anyway to do it so it animates the pan accross?

Comment: easy answer: no, notice how when you go from your carpark to graffitti it's smooth but others are not. reason being, documentation says:panTo(latLng:LatLng)

If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

Comment: I mean i'm sure you could add something that would do it by traveling along a polyline or something, but that's a question for another "question".